# How to listen on a network port in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, port, listen

I am trying to make an application for iPhone that can listen for traffick on a specific network port.

A server on my network is sending out messages (different status messages for devices the server handles) on a specific port.

My problem is that when I make a thread and makePairWithSocket I block the port for others who want to send messages to the server, so I only want to listen to the traffic on a specifyed port and then check for specific heraders and then use those messages.
I know how to make the connection and talk to the server using write and read streams, but then I makePairWithSocket and block the port for all other devices on the network

Any one that has any suggestions on how to listen on a port in Objective-C without pairing with the server?

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Answer (score 4):

Check out CocoaAsyncSocket. It gives you a nice and structured way (with delegates) to send and receive data... also with multiple clients. The documentation is quite good. [project link](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/)

edit: Have a look at the AsyncUdpSocket class for a stateless UDP connection.

Comment: I have had a look at that project site before, but I can't really find anything that will do this without connecting to the server and blocking the port. Do you have any ideas on how to get around that with AsyncSocket?

Comment: found this: -acceptOnAddress:port:error:
What do I create to use this? If I have a thread, how does it work? -acceptOnAddress:port:error: I guess this is what I'm after, to accept connections from a specific host on a specifi port, but how would I implement it so I can listen to it in the background?

Comment: A server can accept multiple connection on a single port. The server's AsyncSocketDelegate has the receive method "- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag;" where the "sock" parameter belongs to the client sending the data. You can store the "sock" parameter and use [sock writeData:] to send data to this specific client. So the port is not blocked. You do not need to disconnect any connection. Have a look at the examples provided with CococaAsyncSocket.

Comment: Where do I find the examples?

Comment: AsyncSocket *as = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self]; NSError *e;

if([as acceptOnInterface:IP port:PORT error:&e])
 NSLog(@"Success");
else NSLog(@"Fail:%@", e);

General CFsocket error is what I get when I use the above code, shouldn't that work?
I make the connection and set up a socket to listen to, haven't set the delagets yet cause I want to make the connection work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this requires network support well below the socket API level, perhaps at the hardware driver level, assuming the packets are even being routed to your device.

Comment: I think he wants to capture a UDP broadcast packet, which can be done at the socket API level.

Comment: The server will send a response to that IP that sent the question, so I want to pair up and send a question then close connection and wait for an answer addressed to me. But if I stay paired the server wont send the answer cause I am blocking the port and it will think I am going to send more data.
Can you accept "calls" without having the connection?

Comment: I can hard code the IP of the iPhone in the server so it send to that IP when there is a status change. But how do I accept the connection without pairing and blocking the port?