# Iphone listen a tcp port

Tags: ios, tcp, port

I read some suggested links from the other answers to similar questions. [Article1](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551), [Library1](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket), [Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630519/how-to-listen-on-a-network-port-in-objective-c). However, I couldn't figure out how to do the following application.

Basically, I send to Iphone's IP and a chosen port (let's say port: 2020) a string. And I want to show this string on the Iphone's UI. So, let's check the following example code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString* str;
    while(true)
    {
         str = ReadLineFromPort(2020);
         myLabel.text = str;
    }
}
```

I expect the `ReadLineFromPort()` method to have the following duty:

> Read until you see a line break (i.e., '\n') and when you see the line break return the string. (Similar to the [C# StreamReader.Readline method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx).)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Since I'm not a pro IOS developer I need a basic one though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listening to some TCP port does require some things to set up.

A good choice would be to use Robbie Hanson's [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).

There you'll find an example for Echo Server (in RunLoop/XCode/EchoServer.

True, this XCode project was generated for OSX but you can simply create an
empty iOS project and copy-paste most of the code.

There is no 'read until break' functionality though - but it is simple
enough to implement while copying data to receive buffer.

EDIT:

You'd typically want to modify `onSocket: didReadData: withTag:`

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    NSData *strData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:strData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(str)
    {
      myLabel.text = str;   
    }
}
```

Now, this code does not detect `\n` in incoming data. You could for example
define an ivar or property `rx_buffer`

```
NSMutableString *rx_buffer;
```

which would be *built* with

```
rx_buffer = [rx_buffer stringByAppendingString: str];
```

until you detect `\n` in `str`.

Comment: Yeah, there is quite a lot of work included with even simple TCP listener.

Comment: Yes. Finally, I was able to translate EchoServer application into a Iphone application. It works now... Thank you for the advice.